How to pass Dictionary<string, string> in MultiPartHttpRequest along with file in c#
I have a requirement where i need to pass Dictionary<string, string> filters  as parameter in MultiPartHttpRequest. file is uploading but filters is going as null. If some one can help me sending dictionary correctly.
below is my code for sending request. Document is correctly uploading but filters are always empty. requesting some help to resolve the issue.
 private async Task<string> SendMultiPartHttpRequest(string url, Dictionary<string,string> headers, NameValueCollection values, Dictionary<string,MemoryStream> files)
 {
     string boundary = "----------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
     // The first boundary
     byte[] boundaryBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
     // The last boundary
     byte[] trailer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");

     // Create the request and set parameters
     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
     request.Timeout = 100000;
     request.ReadWriteTimeout = 100000;
     request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
     request.Method = "POST";
     request.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*");
     request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
     request.Headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
     //request.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive", "36000");

     // Get request stream
     Stream requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();

     if (headers != null && headers.Any())
     {
         foreach (var key in headers.Keys)
         {
             request.Headers.Add(key, headers[key]);
         }
     }

     if (values != null)
     {
         foreach (string key in values.Keys)
         {
             // Write item to stream
             byte[] formItemBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\";\r\n\r\n{1}", key, values[key]));
             await requestStream.WriteAsync(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);
             await requestStream.WriteAsync(formItemBytes, 0, formItemBytes.Length);
         }
     }

     Dictionary<string, string> filters = new Dictionary<string, string>
         {
            { "IsConfidential", "true" },
             { "IsArchived", "false" }
         };


     // Add Filters if provided
     if (filters != null && filters.Any())
     {
         // Serialize the Filters dictionary into a JSON string
         string filtersJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filters);
         byte[] filtersBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
             $"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Filters\"\r\n\r\n{filtersJson}");

         // Write the boundary and Filters data
         await requestStream.WriteAsync(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);
         await requestStream.WriteAsync(filtersBytes, 0, filtersBytes.Length);
     }
     
     if (files != null && files.Any())
     {
         foreach (string key in files.Keys)
         {
             int bytesRead = 0;
             byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
             byte[] formItemBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n", "DataFile", key));
             await requestStream.WriteAsync(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);
             await requestStream.WriteAsync(formItemBytes, 0, formItemBytes.Length);

             MemoryStream memoryStream = files[key];

             while ((bytesRead = memoryStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
             {
                 // Write file content to stream, byte by byte
                 await requestStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
             }
         }
     }

     // Write trailer and close stream
     await requestStream.WriteAsync(trailer, 0, trailer.Length);
     requestStream.Close();

     using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader((await request.GetResponseAsync()).GetResponseStream()))
     {
         return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
     };
 }


U can't put the filters inside Content-Disposition. Create your own attribute in header and place the serialized filters as a value to it.

Why are you using HttpWebRequest given it's deprecated?  MultipartFormDataContent supports this out of the box with HttpClient.

@DA Thanks for your time. i am passing other string values in content-disposition
if (values != null)
{
foreach (string key in values.Keys)
{
// Write item to stream
byte[] formItemBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="{0}";\r\n\r\n{1}", key, values[key]));
await requestStream.WriteAsync(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);
await requestStream.WriteAsync(formItemBytes, 0, formItemBytes.Length);
}
}

@Charlieface i will change.  but any idea how can i pass dictionary

Honestly I don't understand why you are using HttpWebRequest given it's deprecated and much more difficult to use. MultipartFormDataContent supports all this out of the box with HttpClient.
private static HttpClient _client = new HttpClient(new SocketsHttpHandler
{
    ConnectTimeout = 100,
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All,
});

private async Task<string> SendMultiPartHttpRequest(string url, Dictionary<string, string> headers, NameValueCollection values, Dictionary<string, MemoryStream> files)
{
    using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
    using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "*/*");
    request.Headers.ConnectionClose = false;

    if (headers != null)
    {
        foreach (var kvp in headers)
        {
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
    }

    if (values != null)
    {
        foreach (var kvp in values)
        {
            content.Add(new StringContent(kvp.Value), kvp.Key);
        }
    }

    var filters = new Dictionary<string, object>  // probably need to pass bool directly
    {
        { "IsConfidential", true },
        { "IsArchived", false }
    };

    string filtersJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(filters);
    content.Add(new StringContent(filtersJson), "Filters");

    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (var kvp in files)
        {
            content.Add(new StreamContent(kvp.Value), "DataFile", kvp.Key);
        }
    }

    using var response = _client.SendAsync(request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var result = await response.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return result;
}

The above is a strict implementation of your own code. Having said that, I have no idea what this URL endpoint is actually expecting, so no idea if that's what is actuualy needed.
